# Convert an String to an array of doubles split with non-number characters

Tags: java, string

I know how I can split a string with a special character like space:

```
String numbers = "22 14 10 8 70";
int [] n1 = new int [numbers.length()];
for(int n = 0; n < numbers.length(); n++) {
    n1[n] = Integer.parseInt(numbers.split(" ")[n]);
}
```

But I want to split String with any non-number(also negative sign and floating point) type of characters; like this string:

```
String numbers = "22+14/10*8-70";
```

Comment: Regex is not the way to go for this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I remove regex from tags

Comment: [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) can split over a regex string

Comment: @jedwards this looks like formula parsing, and Regex is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try this algorithm [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

> The shunting-yard algorithm is a method for parsing mathematical
>   expressions specified in infix notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also transform the available expression first to [Postfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) expression and then evaluate it. [Here](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/ds/ds10/tutorial/tutorial2.pdf) is an explanation about it.

Answer (score -1):

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) can split over a regex string:

```
String numbers = "22+14/10*8-70";
String[] elements = numbers.split("[^0-9\\.]");
for(String e : elements)
{
    System.out.println("Element: " + e);
}
```

Prints:

```
Element: 22
Element: 14
Element: 10
Element: 8
Element: 70
```

Comment: Try again, now with *22.5+14.0/10.0*8.0-70.5*

Comment: I am with @LuiggiMendoza I want doubles in results

Comment: @Ehsan, Doubles are parsed correctly, negative numbers are not.  By the way, it's nice when you edit your question to put an "Edit" line in there, so downvote-happy people like Luiggi realize that the answer was posted before the question edited.

Comment: @jedwards two people with higher rep (63k and 105k) answered this before you and they deleted their answers since didn't solved the question. Also,please read [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862), section 7.

Comment: The answer was posted before the question was edited.  And it serves as decent answer for the general, non-formula parsing case.  Note that the question title is *Convert an String to an array of doubles split with non-number characters*, not *Formula Parsing*.  You've pointed out and I conceded that this won't work with formulas with negative numbers.  I've also upvoted an answer that is better positioned for the question as it was edited.  Its just a bit odd that instead of being constructive and answering the question yourself, you just police with downvotes... oh well.